# Front camera saving audio and back camera not saving anything in samsung s6 lollipop

Tags: android, android-camera, video-recording

I am using this code for recording video in Background. The app working good for android 4.4.4(Samsung s3 new) but i can only save audio for front camera in Samsung s6 (lollopop) when i chose back camera for lollipop its not saving anything.
Please help
I am using this code
    [Recording video in background](https://github.com/pickerweng/CameraRecorder)

Comment: Hi,

from the code base i can see in the file 
https://github.com/pickerweng/CameraRecorder/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/meowme/camerarecorder/RecorderService.java

Have you tried setting different params for the following:

recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.html

check whether the configs are working for particular device.

Comment: @ManojK thank you, how to check it? please

Comment: recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT); recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT); try using this params.

Comment: let me check, please and be stay with me thanks

Comment: @ManojK actually the app working good on samsung s3 new(4.4.4) and 4.2 devices but it stop and not working at motorola xt919, motorola g and galaxy s6, i am changing the code and let you know

Comment: ok sure, a stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: @ManojK sir, now it record only 15 second video and then stop on Motorolla Device and in Lollipop it still not recording any thing

Answer (score 0):

I had really headstroke but i got solve my problem. I change every thing to default and now its working really good.

```
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);

    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);

     mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
      mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
```